# How can I use devise with rails 4 to store data on a second model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

There are some similar questions but not clear answer. 
I want to use devise I was able to add more fields and store them on the user table. 
If I want to collect data during the signup process that belong to another table
is it possible to do it through devise controller or do I have to write my own one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use your own.  Override the registrations controller and add it to your routes to point your devise registration to your new registrations controller.

```
# app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    # add custom create logic here
    # Strip the fields out of the resource params and save them to 
    # another model then you can call super to have the method behave as it normal:
    super
  end

  def update
    super
  end
end
```

Then add it to your routes

```
# app/config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
```

Depending on how you're structuring your form you might need to add the extra fields to the devise model (typically `User`)  - you can use `attr_accessor :field_name` to do this if you must

Comment: It does work partially,
the problem is that on 
# Strip the fields out of the resource params and save them to
I am not able to get the params.